# Why does it always display the wrong amount of nickels?

Tags: java

I'm making a Java method that takes in an int from 1-99. It can correctly display quarters and dimes, but will not correctly display the nickels. The class is PS1

```
static void problem10(int change)
{
    if (change > 99)
    {
        return;
    }
    //declaring variables
    int numQuarters;
    int numDimes;
    int numNickels;
    int numPennies;
    
    //figuring out change for each denomination
    numQuarters = change / 25;
    if (numQuarters <= 0.1){
        numQuarters = 0;
    }
    numDimes = (change - numQuarters*25) /10 ;
     if (numDimes <= 0.1){
        numDimes = 0;
    }
    numNickels = (change - numQuarters * 25) - (numDimes * 10) / 5; //fix nickels
     if (numNickels < 1){
        numNickels = 0;
    }
    numPennies = (change - numQuarters * 25) - (numDimes * 10) - (numNickels * 5) / 1;
    if (numPennies < 1){
        numPennies = 0;
    }
    
    //printing the correct change for each denomination
    System.out.println("Your change is " + numQuarters + " quarters " + numDimes + " dimes " + numNickels + " nickels " + numPennies + " pennies ");
}
```

The output it gives for PS1.problem10(35); is:

```
Your change is 1 quarters 1 dimes 8 nickels 0 pennies
```

Comment: You need either more or fewer parentheses. `(numDimes * 10) / 5` is calculated before the subtraction. [PEMDAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

Comment: You're also comparing ints and floats, as in `numQuarters <= 0.1`... which seems odd. You may need to look up the modulo operator.

Comment: Comparing ints to 0.1 seems like you're trying to fix a double value. Doing this to an int isn't useful. An integer value will always be an integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need extra parentheses like;

```
    numNickels = ((change - numQuarters * 25) - (numDimes * 10)) / 5; //fix nickels
     if (numNickels < 1){
        numNickels = 0;
    }
    numPennies = ((change - numQuarters * 25) - (numDimes * 10) - (numNickels * 5)) / 1;
    if (numPennies < 1){
        numPennies = 0;
    }
```